# Rails loading ActiveSupport regex with ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, ruby-on-rails-6

When I call `'返回'.titleize` on a Chinese-language string in the Rails 6 app on my server, I get an error:

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ISO-8859-1 regexp with UTF-8 string)

The source for the titleize function leads to the following in ActiveSupport::Inflector:

```rb
def titleize(word, keep_id_suffix: false)
  humanize(underscore(word), keep_id_suffix: keep_id_suffix).gsub(/\b(?<!\w['’`()])[a-z]/) do |match|
    match.capitalize
  end
end
```

Although calling `ActiveSupport::Inflector.titleize('返回')` gives the error above, if I just copy the function body and run it as follows, there's no error --- I just get the correct titleize behaviour:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.humanize(ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore('返回'), keep_id_suffix: false).gsub(/\b(?<!\w['’`()])[a-z]/) do |match|
  match.capitalize
end
```

I guess that the regular expression `/\b(?<!\w['’()])[a-z]/` is getting compiled with a ISO-8859-1 encoding when ActiveSupport::Inflector loads but is compiling with a different encoding when I run it in my Rails console, but I don't see anything I can do with this information.

What can I do to get the Rails helper `titleize` to work on my server as intended?

I'm on Rails 6, Ruby 2.6.6, and `ENV["LANG"]` is `en_US.utf8`.

Comment: you still struggle with that bug :D , i think for now you can work around by extend `String#titleize` and rescue `Encoding::CompatibilityError` ( but obviously the same bug likely happen to you in future).

Comment: `/\b(?<!\w['’()])[a-z]/.encoding` actually is UTF-8, not ASCII